# How do override hitTest to allow my subview to receive touch events?

Tags: ios, objective-c, hittest

I have a UIView that contains another view, which its self contians a UIButton. The problem is the MENUVIEW is really narrow so my DROPDOWN extends over it and when it does and the user taps (K) nothing happens. I know that I have to override HitTest: and pointInside: but I am not sure in which view and how?

Do I override hitTest in A, B or K? And pointInside A, B, or K?

Example:

```
(A) is MENUVIEW, the parent of all views
(B) is DROPDOWN, a subview of MENUVIEW
(K) is UIBUTTON, a subview of DROPDOWN
```

Diagram:

```
    +---------------+
    |A              |         
    |               |               
    |               |         
    |               |         
    |+--------------|----------+
    ||B             |  +K---+  |
    ||              |  +----+  |
    |+--------------|----------+
    +---------------+
```

UPDATE:

Here is the code I have placed in, but it doesn't work. With the code below I click on B then B will open and show K, but then K still isn't clickable. Point inside isn't being called on (A)?

```
    #pragma mark - Clickable Area()
    - (UIView *)hitTest:(CGPoint)point withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
    {
        CGFloat radius = 200.0;
        CGRect frame = CGRectMake(self.dropDownMenu.frame.origin.x, self.dropDownMenu.frame.origin.y + 50,
                                  200,
                                  174); <-- this B's frame area minus the part of B inside A (i.e. just K and the part of B outside A)

        if (CGRectContainsPoint(frame, point)) {
            return self.dropDownMenu;
        } else {
            return [super hitTest:point withEvent:event];
        }
        return nil;
    }

    - (BOOL)pointInside:(CGPoint)point withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
    {
        if (CGRectContainsPoint(self.bounds, point)) {
            return YES;
        }
        return NO;
    }

    @end
```

Comment: Please provide some source code. Also, here's something which may or may not be helpful: check `userInteractionEnabled`.

Comment: Also, why are you messing with hitTest and friends?

Answer (score 0):

You should make a big enough parentview. and override the d's pointInside and hittest
when the point not in the a|b|c area, return nil to let the below view respond the event.(return nil means userinteractionenabled =  NO)

```
- (UIView *) hitTest:(CGPoint)point withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
1.convert b's frame to the view D
if (point inside B's convertedFrame) {
    return B;
}
xxxxx {
    return A
}
XXXXX {
    return C;
}
return nil;
}

+-----------------------------+
+---------------+           D |
|A              |             |
|               |             |  
|               |             |
|               |             |
|+--------------|----------+  |
||B             |  +K---+  |  |
||              |  +----+  |  |
|+--------------|----------+  |
+---------------+             |
+-----------------------------+
```

if b respond the event, then k can respond even the k not inside a.

Comment: I can't make (D) or (A) bigger.  (B) has to fit in (A) that is only 60px wide but (B) is 200px wide.  Think dropdown or slide out menu.

Comment: it doesn't matter, you can override A's hittest instead, and return subview K or b.hitTest:event. remember that when not in the area a|b|k, return nil to let the under view respond